# Spring MVC Pass multiple list from controller to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have two objects `Employee` and `Department` Employee contains the `dept_id`. What i want to do is display the content of `Employee` in a table in jsp page. But instead of displaying `dept_id` i want to display `dept_name` from `Department` table. So far i have my controller method as:

```
public ModelAndView viewEmployee(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeService.getAllEmployee();
        List<Department> departmentList = new ArrayList<Department>();
        for (Employee e : employeeList) {
            departmentList.add(departmentService.getDepartment(e.getDept_id()));
        }
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employee", employeeList);
        model.put("department", departmentList);

        return new ModelAndView("viewEmployee", "model", model);
    }
```

**viewEmployee.jsp**

```
<table border="1px" bordercolor="black" width=80% align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                    <td>Salary</td>
                    <td>Department</td>
                    <td>Action</td>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${model.employeeList}" var="element">

                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${element.name}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${element.gender}" /></td>

                        <td><c:out value="${element.salary}" /></td>

                        <td>display Department Name here </td>

                        <td><a
                            href="<c:url value="editEmployee.htm">  
                    <c:param name="emp_id" value="${element.id}"/>  
        </c:url>  
    ">Edit</a>
                            <a
                            href="<c:url value="deleteEmployee.htm">  
                    <c:param name="emp_id" value="${element.id}"/>  
        </c:url>  
    ">Delete</a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </c:forEach>
            </table>
```

Any help? I am not being able to display the map content to the jsp page.

Comment: do you have setters and getters in your POJO's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be `<c:forEach items="${model.employee}" var="element">`

Also department should be a property of Employee , so that you can use `${employee.department.name}`

Comment: Well, how to get department name then?

Comment: if you dont have department as a property of employee, then you will have to iterate over department list and check for the department with employee.dept_id and print its name,